# Twilio REST API How to get Sid

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am still new to Twilio.  I am writing a PHP script which will connect to Twilio and parse some information about calls.  I am using the code from this page:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call

Here is my code:

```
require_once '../twilio-library/Services/Twilio.php';

// Twilio REST API version
$version = '2010-04-01';

// Set our AccountSid and AuthToken
$sid = 'abc132xxxxx';
$token = 'xxxxeeffv';

// Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);

// Loop over the list of calls and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->calls as $call) {
    echo "->".$call->Sid."<- <br/>";


}
```

The browser just outputs many blanks.  No Sid values.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Try doing the following to get call information.

```
<?php
require_once '../twilio-library/Services/Twilio.php';

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = 'abc132xxxxx';
$token = 'xxxxeeffv';
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Loop over the list of calls and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->calls as $call) {
    echo $call->sid;
}
```

Notice that if you're using the latest version of the library, you don't need to specify a version on your request. Double check that the path `../twilio-library/Services/Twilio.php` is correct for you though.

If you're only testing, you could move the file `Twilio.php` to the same directory where your code is and just import `Twilio.php` on it.

If you then decide to filter the logs by date, here's how you would do it.

```
// Loop over the list of calls and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array(
        "Status" => "completed",
        "StartTime>" => "2015-03-01",
        "StartTime<" => "2015-05-10"
    )) as $call
) {
    echo $call->sid;
}
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but your code results in the same output as my original code did.  If I { var_dump($call);}  then i see a ton of information, including the Sid.  So i tried digging into the objects and arrays which $call contains, but I havent isolated the Sid yet.  Even if I do get it this way, it seems hacky and likely to fail one day... why is it so hard to get this Sid?

Comment: Ok, I've added another example which I just tested locally. If it's taking a  long time for the results to come back it might be because you have a large number of records in the log, so filtering will do the trick. My second example returns data a lot quicker.

Comment: I just realized it was the use of upper case first letters. Twilio's Methods/Functions are capitalized in the API Docs, but if you call the functions, using an uppercase first letter,  the function returns an empty string, not an error.  This might actually be the cause of every trouble I've had so far.

Looking back over your code, I see that the first example you sent had "$call->Sid"  and like mine, it failed.   The second example had "$call->sid".  What a schmozzle
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've corrected my code sample for future reference.

Comment: I'm curious why is it necessary to begin the answer with Twilio Developer Evangelist here? I've noticed it at multiple Twilio related answers. Does it improve the answer content or make it somehow easier to understand?